# App like NetLimiter Monitor for OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, software-rec, monitoring

What app or apps replicate the functionality of NetLimiter Monitor

- near realtime per-process and total bandwidth monitoring
- data usage record

on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) and [Hands Off!](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/) both offer realtime process activity monitoring in a floating window. They both have an activity bar, but I don't believe they record total overall data usage.

[IStatMenus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) will actually show you the aggregate bandwidth usage in the menubar.

Comment: Little Snitch is a firewall. It will either stop traffic to an app, or enable it. But NOT limit bandwidth to an app. For example you want Skype to consume only 50kpbs not above it, you cant do this in Little Snitch.

Answer (score 0):

[LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) has some network monitoring, even though it is primarily an application firewall.